# Confusion about virtual/new/override

Tags: c#, virtual, overriding, new-operator, keyword

I am a bit confused about the `virtual`/`new`/`override` thing. Here's an example:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void mVVirtual() { Console.WriteLine("A::mVVirtual"); }
}

class B : A
{
    public virtual void mVVirtual() { Console.WriteLine("B::mVVirtual"); }
}

class C : B
{
    public override void mVVirtual() { Console.WriteLine("C::mVVirtual"); }
}


class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B b1 = new C();
        b1.mVVirtual();    //C::mVVirtual ... I understand this

        A a2 = new C();
        a2.mVVirtual();    //A::mVVirtual ... ???
    }
}
```

I don't get why in the second call we get `A::mVVirtual`. I usually treat these issues with this "algorithm":

1. Check the type of the variable holding the reference for the object for an instance method called `mVVirtual`? Doesn't have one...but does have a virtual method with that signature and name!
2. Virtual method? Let's then check the type of the object being held by `a2` (`C`) for an overriding of that method. It has one -> Executes `C::mVVirtual`!

Where is my "algorithm" wrong? I really am confused by this, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: @John Gietzen: I was referring to the train of thought i conduct when dealing with these issues...its a mental algorithm if you like. It has worked for me so far, but this question really is bothering me.

Comment: Algorithm - A finite set of unambiguous instructions performed in a prescribed sequence to achieve a goal. Looks pretty much like an algorithm to me, John.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how you think of virtual methods. Every instance of a class has "boxes" to hold methods. When you mark a method as `virtual` it says make a new "box" and put a method in it. When you mark a method as `override` in a derived class, it keeps the "box" from the base class but puts a new method in it.

So here you have a class `A` and a method named `mVVirtual` that is marked as `virtual`. This says make a new "box" named `mVVirtual` and put a method in it with definition

```
Console.WriteLine("A::mVVirtual");
```

Then you have a derived class `B` and a method named `mVVirtual` that is marked as `virtual`. This says make a new "box" named `mVVirtual` and put a method in it with definition

```
Console.WriteLine("B::mVVirtual");
```

**In particular, the "box" inherited from `A` is hidden! It can not be seen by objects that are typed as `B`s or classes that derive from `B`.**

Then you have a derived class `C` and a method named `mVVirtual` that is marked as `override`. This says take the "box" named `mVVirtual` inherited from `B` and put a different method in it with definition

```
Console.WriteLine("C::mVVirtual");
```

Now, when you have

```
B b1 = new C(); 
b1.mVVirtual();
```

you are telling the compiler that `b1` is a `B` so that `b1.mVVirtual()` looks in the "box" `mVVirtual` and finds the method with definition

```
Console.WriteLine("C::mVVirtual");
```

because `b1` is really a `C` and that is what is in the "box" `mVVirtual` for instances of `C`.

But when you have

```
A a2 = new C(); 
a2.mVVirtual();
```

you are telling the compiler that `a2` is an `A` and so it looks in the "box" and finds

```
Console.WriteLine("A::mVVirtual");
```

The compiler can not know that `a2` is really a `C` (you've typed it as an `A`) so it does not know that `a2` is really an instance of a class that is derived from a class that has hidden the "box" `mVVirtual` defined by `A`. What it does know is that `A` has a "box" named `mVVirtual` and so it emits code to invoke the method in that "box".

So, to try to put this succinctly:

```
class A {
    public virtual void mVVirtual() { Console.WriteLine("A::mVVirtual"); }
}
```

defines a class that has a "box" with full name `A::mVVirtual` but that you can refer to by the name `mVVirtual`.

```
class B : A 
{
    // "new" method; compiler will tell you that this should be marked "new" for clarity.
    public virtual void mVVirtual() { Console.WriteLine("B::mVVirtual"); }
}
```

defines a class that has a "box" with full name `B::mVVirtual` but that you can refer to by the name `mVVirtual`. Referring to `B.mVVirtual` will not refer to the "box" with full name `A::mVVirtual`; that "box" can not be seen by objects that are typed as `B`s (or classes that derive from `B`).

```
class C : B
{
    public override void mVVirtual() { Console.WriteLine("C::mVVirtual"); }
}
```

defines a class that takes the "box" with full name `B::mVVirtual` and puts a different method in it.

Then

```
A a2 = new C(); 
a2.mVVirtual();
```

says that `a2` is an `A` so that `a2.mVVirtual` looks in the "box" with full name `A::mVVirtual` and invokes the method in that "box". This is why you see

```
A::mVVirtual
```

on the console.

There are two other method annotaters. `abstract` makes a new "box" does not put a method definition in the "box". `new` makes a new "box" and puts a method definition in the "box" but does not allow derived classes to put their own definitions of the method in the "box" (use `virtual` if you want to do that).

Sorry for being long-winded but I hope that helps.

Comment: Well it makes sense from this point of view...but then the "algorithm" that i was talking about falls apart because i thought that when the compiler sees the method marked as virtual, it searches in the object's type for a overridden version of the method and if it exists, executes it! If it doesnt exist, we climb all the way throug the hierarchy searcing for an override...

I dont know if im explaining myself properly...

Comment: You are explaining yourself properly; I understand the way that you are thinking of it. What my explanation shows is that that way of thinking of it is a little off.

Comment: But for the majority of cases my way of thinking about it is good, right? Only in this case it's a little off.

Comment: If it were impossible to hide the "box" your thinking would be fine.

Comment: To clarify, It is NOT the instance of a type that has these 'boxes' It is the TYPE itself. Every Type has a "method Table" with pointers to all the methods in that type. Each Types' method table is structured with the virtual methods first, from `Object` (furthest up the inheritance chain) first. to the virtual methods declared in the type itself. After are the non-virtual methods. When the compiler resolves a virtual method call it goes to the method table for the Type of the object itself, whereas for a non-virtual call it goes to the method table for declared type of the variable.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE : For a more information about this language feature, see the follow-up question here:  [More about Virtual / new...plus interfaces!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072983/more-about-virtual-new-plus-interfaces/2073762)

Jason's answer is correct. To sum it up a bit more succinctly.

You have three methods. Call them MA, MB and MC.

You have two "boxes", or, as they're usually called, slots. We'll stick with Jason's nomenclature. Call them BOX1 and BOX2.

"A" defines BOX1.

"B" defines BOX2.

"C" defines no box; it reuses BOX2.

When you say "new A()", BOX1 is filled in with MA.

When you say "new B()", BOX1 is filled in with MA and BOX2 is filled in with MB.

When you say "new C()", BOX1 is filled in with MA and BOX2 is filled in with MC.

Now suppose you have a variable of type A, and a call to the method. Reason like the compiler. The compiler says "are there any boxes on type A that match this name?"  Yes, there is one: BOX1.  Therefore, the compiler generates a call to the contents of BOX1.

As we've seen, the contents of BOX1 is always MA, so MA is always called no matter whether the variable is actually holding a reference to A, B, or C.

Now suppose you have a variable of type B, and a call to the method. Again, think like the compiler. The compiler says "are there any boxes on type B that matches this name?" Yes, there are TWO boxes that match by name. The compiler says "which of those two is more closely associated with B?"  The answer is BOX2, because B declares BOX2.  Therefore, the compiler generates a call to BOX2.

This will call MB if the variable contains a B, because in a B, BOX2 contains MB.  This will call MC if the variable contains a C, because in a C, BOX2 contains MC.

Is that now clear? Remember, *overload resolution just chooses the box*. What the contents of the box are depend upon the object at runtime.

Comment: Got it...Jason's answer really cracked it open for me! Thanks guys ;)

Comment: @EricLippert Great explanation. 
just have one confusion, 
**When you say "new C()", BOX1 is filled in with MA and BOX2 is filled in with MC.**  
So BOX2 (box of class B) is filled with MC , but if we do 

`class C : B
    {
        public override void mVVirtual()
        {
            base.mVVirtual();
            Console.WriteLine("C::mVVirtual");
        }
    }
`
it will print 
**B::mVVirtual
C::mVVirtual**

but I thought Box2 is filled with MC.

Comment: @Posto: "base" calls are non-virtual calls. The compiler generates a call directly to the base class method, rather than doing an indirect call by looking up the contents of the virtual method slot.

Comment: Okay, can you point to any resources (online docs etc) where I can get details understanding for non-virtual or virtual calls

Comment: @Posto: https://ericlippert.com/2011/03/17/implementing-the-virtual-method-pattern-in-c-part-one/

Answer (score 3):

Do you have warnings hidden?  When I do what you've done, I get this warning:

> 'ProjectName.ClassName.B.mVVirtual()' hides inherited member 'ProjectName.ClassName.A.mVVirtual()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

If you used `override` in class B, you wouldn't have this problem; both cases would give you "C::mVVirtual".  Since you're not using `override` in class B, there's an *implicit* `new` in front of the method.  This breaks the inheritance chain.  Your code is calling a method on type A, and there are no inheriting classes that override that method due to the implicit `new`.  So it has to call class A's implementation.

Comment: Yeah i have warnings, but see, this is an exam question and the questions are made not regarding if the code throws warnings or not...it only has to compile correctly. And the question is: what is the output on the console and why?

I understand that in class B we should be doing new void mVVirtual()..., but i guess that if we let it be virtual it will have the same effect (create a new slot on the type's method tables), but of course throwing a warning.

Comment: In class B you should either use `new` or `override`. The code given doesn't use either one. The compiler *could* raise an error in such a case; but instead it chooses to assume that you meant `new`, and shows a warning. The only effect of `virtual` in B is to let you override that new method in C; it doesn't have any connection to A at all.

Comment: I've used new in class B and the output remains A::mVVirtual...and i still can't see why :S

Comment: @Bruno: because what you want in this case is to label B::mVVirtual as `virtual override`.  When you think about the combined meaning of the modifiers you get the behavior you expect.  It's just that because A's implementation was `virtual`, when you declare B's implementation as `override`, it inherits the `virtual` modifier automatically, so there's no need to specify it redundantly.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to think of it is that virtual methods use the ***actual*** (or ***concrete***) type of the object to decide what implementation to execute, where non-Virtual methods use the 'declared type of the variabe you are using to access the method to decide which to run...

*Override* means you are writing a method that is going to 'replace' the implementation for a virtual or abstract method (with the same name/signature) higher up the inheritance chain.

*new* is used when there is a non-virtual method up the chain with the same name/signature, which the method you are adding will replace...

The difference is as follows

```
class base     { public virtual void  foo() { Console.write("base.foo"); } }
class derived  { public override void foo() { Console.write("derived.foo"); } }
base b = new base();
b.foo()  // prints "base.foo" // no issue b is a base and variable is a base
base b = new derived();
b.foo(); // prints "derived.foo" because concrete tyoe is derived, not base
```

but

```
class base     { public void  foo() { Console.write("base.foo"); } }
class derived  { public new void foo() { Console.write("derived.foo"); } }
base b = new base();
b.foo()  // prints "base.foo" // no issue b is a base and variable is a base
base b = new derived();
b.foo(); // prints "base.foo" because variable b is base. 
derived d = b as derived;
d.foo()    //  prints "derived.foo" - now variable d is declared as derived.
```

Your second call prints `A::mvVirtual` because that method (`mVVirtual`) is actually ***not*** virtual, (in spite of it's name), because it has the *new* specifier...  So it decides based on the variable type, which is A.

To explain what is going on technically,  Every Type has a "method Table" with pointers to all the methods in that type. (It is NOT the instance of a type that has this table, It is the *TYPE* itself.)  Each Types' method table is structured with all acessible *virtual* methods first, from `object` (furthest up the inheritance chain) at the beginning, to the virtual methods declared in the type itself, at the end. Then, after all the virtual methods are represented, all the non-virtual methods are added, again, from any non-virtual methods in `object`, first, all the way to any non-virtual methods in the Type itself.  The table is structured this way so that the offsets for all virtual metods will be identical in all derived classes' method tables, since the compiler may call these methods from variables declared as other types, even from code in other methods declared and implemented in base types of the concrete class.

When the compiler resolves a virtual method call it goes to the method table for the Type of the object itself, (the ***concrete*** type), whereas for a non-virtual call it goes to the method table for declared type of the variable.   So if you call a virtual method, even from code in a base type, if the actual concrete type is Type derived from this base type, the compiler goes to the method table for that concrete type.

If you call a non-virtual method, (no matter how far down the inheritance change the actual object's type might be), The compiler access the method table for the variab;es' declared type.  This table has ***nothing*** in from any derived types  furthur down the chain.

Comment: key is that in the second case, because of the new,  he is calling a non-virtual method...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand it

A is the base class
B inherit A but doesn't override it
C inherit B but does override it

Since you are declaring A but initialize C, it will ignore the override because the base class is A and A never get overridden from B.