# Method Overriding in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Given the following:

```
class BC
{
  public void Display()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("BC::Display");
  }
}

class DC : BC
{
  new public void Display()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("DC::Display");
  }
}

class Demo
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     BC b;
     b = new BC();
     b.Display();    

     b = new DC();
     b.Display();    
  }
}
```

I understand that the following code calls the base class `Display()` method:

```
BC b;
b = new BC();
b.Display();
```

And that the following lines call the derived class `Display()`, which hides the base class implementation through the use of the `new` keyword:

```
b = new DC();
b.Display();
```

I would like to know what the `new` keyword is doing internally.

The source of this code included the following explanation:

> Since b contains a reference to an object of type DC one would expect the function `Display()` of class DC to get executed. But that does not happen. Instead what is executed is the `Display()` of BC class. That's because the function is invoked based on type of the reference and not to what the reference variable b refers to. Since b is a reference of type BC, the function `Display()` of class BC will be invoked, no matter whom b refers to.

I am very confused about this particular bit: "because the function is invoked based on type of the reference and not to what the reference variable b refers to"

What does "function is invoked based on type of the reference" mean here

```
b = new DC();
b.Display();
```

What is the type of `b` here? It was declared as instance name of class `BC`
but later `b` becomes an instance of class `DC`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is not overriding, but shadowing. The `new` keyword lets you have a `Display` method in both the classes `BC` and `DC`, but the methods are not related at all, they just have the same name.

To override the method you would need to use the `virtual` keyword for the method in the `BC` class, and the `overrides` method in the `DC` class.

When you are shadowing a method, it's the type of the reference that decides which method is used:

```
BC b1;
b1 = new BC();
b1.Display(); // Calls the method in BC

BC b2;
b2 = new DC();
b2.Display(); // Calls the method in BC

DC d1;
d1 = new DC();
d1.Display(); // Calls the method in DC
```

Overriding the method looks like this:

```
class BC {

  public virtual void Display() {
    System.Console.WriteLine("BC::Display");
  }

}

class DC : BC {

  override public void Display() {
    System.Console.WriteLine("DC::Display");
  }

}
```

When overriding a method, the methods are related, and it's the actual type of the object that decides which method is used, not the type of the reference:

```
BC b1;
b1 = new BC();
b1.Display(); // Calls the method in BC

BC b2;
b2 = new DC();
b2.Display(); // Calls the method in DC

DC d1;
d1 = new DC();
d1.Display(); // Calls the method in DC
```

Another difference between overriding and shadowing, is that when you shadow a method the don't have to be similar at all, the `new` keyword just tells the compiler that you want to reuse the identifier for something other than in the base class. When overriding a method, the method signatures have to be the same.

You can for example shadow a public method that takes a `string` with something completely different like a private property of the type `int`:

```
public class X {

  public void XX(string z) { }

}

public class Y : X {

  private new int XX { get; set; }

}

X x = new Y();
x.XX();

Y y = new Y();
y.XX = 42;
```

Comment: you said -- When overriding a method, the methods are related, and it's the actual type of the object that decides which method is used, not the type of the reference. what is the type of reference? meaning here.

Comment: you said -- Another difference between overriding and shadowing, is that when you shadow a method the don't have to be similar at all, the new keyword just tells the compiler that you want to reuse the identifier for something other than in the base class. When overriding a method, the method signatures have to be the same. can u please discuss with sample code that shadow method don't have to be similar at all and overriding a method, the method signatures have to be the same. plzz come with sample code for better understad. thanks

Comment: When you create a variable of type `BC`, it contains a reference of the type `BC`. Even if you create an intance of `DC` and assign to the variable, the type of the reference is still `BC`.

Comment: I added an example above, which shows that you can shadow with something completely different.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know what the new keyword is doing internally.

You're not alone. See the answers to this question:

[Confusion about virtual/new/override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065780/confusion-about-virtual-new-override)

and this follow-up question:

[More about Virtual / new...plus interfaces!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072983/more-about-virtual-new-plus-interfaces/2073762#2073762)

for a detailed but still high-level explanation of how virtual, new, override, and interface implementation are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Display` a virtual function in BC and override in DC, then it will work the way you expect it.

Comment: please discuss in detail how new keyword works and what instruction new keyword gives to compiler.