# Regarding Inheritance C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to understand how inheritance works in C#. I wrote the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal animal = new Dog();
        animal.OverRideMe();
        //animal.NewMethod();
        Dog dog = (Dog)animal;
        dog.OverRideMe();
        dog.NewMethod();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
public abstract class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Constructor");
    }
    public virtual void OverRideMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Base Class's OverRideMe");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived Constructor");
    }
    public override void OverRideMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Derived Class's OverRideMe");
        Console.Read();
    }
    public void NewMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Derived Class's NewMethod");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The CIL(Common Intermediate Language) code for the Main() looks like the following:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 42 (0x2a)
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint
    .locals init (
        [0] class ConsoleApplication1.Animal animal,
        [1] class ConsoleApplication1.Dog dog
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication1.Dog::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication1.Animal::OverRideMe()
    IL_000d: nop
    IL_000e: ldloc.0
    IL_000f: castclass ConsoleApplication1.Dog
    IL_0014: stloc.1
    IL_0015: ldloc.1
    IL_0016: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication1.Animal::OverRideMe()
    IL_001b: nop
    IL_001c: ldloc.1
    IL_001d: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication1.Dog::NewMethod()
    IL_0022: nop
    IL_0023: call int32 [mscorlib]System.Console::Read()
    IL_0028: pop
    IL_0029: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

The lines in CIL that are troubling me are:

```
IL_000f: castclass ConsoleApplication1.Dog
IL_0014: stloc.1
IL_0015: ldloc.1
IL_0016: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication1.Animal::OverRideMe()
IL_001b: nop
IL_001c: ldloc.1
IL_001d: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication1.Dog::NewMethod()
```

After the **castclass** of **animal** to **Dog** type the code executes **dog.OverRideMe();**. This is translated to CIL as

> IL_0016: callvirt instance void
>   ConsoleApplication1.Animal::OverRideMe()

I had cast the **animal** object to **Dog** type. Why should **dog.OverRideMe();** be translated to the above statement in CIL? The output of the above code is:

[image]

This output has nothing to do with Base class **Animal** but CIL still places a call to it.

Comment: I do not understand the need for downvoting this question. At the least leave a comment so that I may improve it.

Comment: Your question is fine, and frankly a good one. Ignore the haters, they are out of control on the site these days IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're invoking a virtual method. Virtual method invocation is determined by the *runtime* type of an object. You can call it a `Dog` all you want, but the compiler is still going to emit instructions to determine the appropriate method to invoke at *runtime*. Starting with the *compile-time* type of `dog`, it walks up the inheritance chain until it finds the "top-level" definition<sup>1</sup> of `OverRideMe` and it emits a virtual method invocation for that. In this case, the highest place in the inheritance chain that `OverRideMe` is defined is in `Animal`; thus, it emits a virtual method invocation for `Animal.OverRideMe`.

Here's a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2066091/45914) that might help you understand what is going on a little better.

<sup>1</sup>: The highest place in the inheritance chain where the method is defined. *Some* care has to be taken here to understand how method hiding and what not impact this.

Comment: You maybe need to take a look at the new keyword in method signature. This will call the method on the actual type not as override.

Comment: @Sebi: There is *no* keyword `new` used to hide any methods in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

It says "callvirt" - the virtual table is associated with "Animal" class so that's where the call should be placed. After resolving the virtual table, during runtime, the intended method will be called.